# Ubuntu 12.04 Unity 3D running slowly

Tags: 12.04, unity, 3d

Okay so I have done a lot of research on this and I am pretty sure this is just me here but I have spent about two days now trying to get unity 3D to stop lagging so much during animations. The system itself is quick but the animations lag so much it just makes it all so ugly. I am running on the new Nvidia 310.19 drivers with better opengl support. I have done plenty of tests to make sure I am hardware accelerated in Unity 3D, and everything checks out.

Why oh why do the animations lag so badly. Once you see the specs you will wonder the same thing.

- Intel Core 2 Duo P7450 2.13 Ghz
- 4GB DDR2 RAM
- 320 GB HDD 7200RPM
- Nvidia GTX260-M 1GB GDDR3+CUDA <------This should more than handle unity 3d

Also I would like to add that I use the CPU indicator to keep at full performance
and I also set Nvidia powermizer at full performance also but it doesn't help either. I have done preload, unity tweaks; nothing works.

I will give any info needed. Even Firefox is laggy sometimes and that is just bad.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67055/slow-lagged-desktop-effects-with-nvidia-card