# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS graphical slow downs

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, gnome, graphics

I have been a Ubuntu lover for many years, and now that I have my own and new workstation set up again, I am dual booting my lovely Ubuntu with W10!
I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and actually tweaked a lot, for various reasons and different problems. I installed the last proprietary NVIDIA drivers, but I am occasionally having random slow downs, and sometimes freezes.

I am currently using Gnome Shell, but if I'm not wrong I experienced the same issues with Unity.
It is really annoying, as I can't work fluently and as fast as I can, and speed is one of my main priorities. I tried to remove as many extensions I could on gnome shell, but I'm absolutely keeping the one I really need for my comforting UX. The effects are almost null, but it shouldn't be absolutely the issue here! I am mostly experiencing this problems with Firefox. (I tried Chrome, is just a bit better)

Something that upset me considerably, is how the system substantially kept freezing and lagging, when I tried to run an old VBox VM! Both guest and host became almost unusable...

By the effects I can determine that it is graphics related, but I don't know what is causing the problem here. On Windows 10, the system is working like a charm (almost I'd say, random audio lags excluded caused by the ALC1150 soundcard)

My workstation specs are the following:

- Intel i7-6700k
- 16GB DDR4 3000MHz CL15
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070
- Samsung NVMe SM961 256GB (3200MB/s read - 1500MB/s write)

I would be really thankful and delighted by any sorts of help  given!!

Cheers, Luca!

edit:
sys logs https://gist.github.com/Sevenarth/66eec491b66218e3262e2b4276d262cf

```
sowia@qwurth:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 5173
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_367, nvidia_367_drm
```

edit: I tried to benchmark my GPU and it is way slower than Windows...

edit: Drivers updated to 375. Huge performance boost, though I noticed that on GNOME it immediately slows down after a while. I have to try Unity, which is amazingly fast...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 done! :D

Comment: I would assume that you need to blacklist the nouveau module as exemplified in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/a/481540/225694)

Comment: I have just updated the drivers to the latest using the 3rd party repository, and the graphics are definitely boosted. Upon system start, it is really fast, but it starts to slow down after a while....

Comment: Please move the "Problem solved" section out of your question into a new answer. Then accept your new answer by clicking green check mark beside it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i discovered the source of the problems. As my graphics card is connected to the motherboard through a PCI-E riser, at a certain point the computer kept unrecognising my graphics card, and that is when i figured that it was the riser that was faulty. I ordered a replacement, and now everything works great as it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

During the freezes you'll have to actually check what the system is doing, or log it somewhere.

You can start by reading out the output of:

- /var/log/syslog
- /var/log/dmesg

Sadly I don't have any suggestions of what might be causing the issues, other then the graphic card driver, which might not be at its best shape yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you give a look to the edit? :)

Comment: Sadly my answer still stands. You'll have to actually post the logs from syslog and dmesg maybe even gpu-manager.log just to see what's going on in the system during the slowdowns.

edit:  Try reinstalling and see if the fresh install might have something to do with it.

Comment: After using Unity for a while, it started to give the same system slow downs, but seems to perform better in any case. I will upload the files in an instant

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Sevenarth/66eec491b66218e3262e2b4276d262cf

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a nvidia card to actually deploy a gnome ubuntu to test the driver, but I suspect it might be the key to your problem, a fast search on google took me to this answer:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/67055/slow-laggy-desktop-effects-with-nvidia-card

Please check it out and see if it is any help.